# sql table pivot

Tags: sql, pivot

My table currently contains:

```
blog | id | attribute | value
p    | 1  |  pid      | abc1
p    | 1  |  date     | abc2
p    | 1  |  title    | abc3
p    | 2  |  id       | abc1
p    | 2  |  date     | abc2
p    | 2  |  title    | abc3
p    | 3  |  id       | abc1
p    | 3  |  date     | abc2
p    | 3  |  title    | abc3
```

I need to change this to:

```
blog | id | postid | date | title
p    | 1  | abc1   | abc2 | abc3
p    | 2  | abc1   | abc2 | abc3
p    | 3  | abc1   | abc2 | abc3
```

what is the best way to do this in sql?

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Comment: In `attrbute` column you have `pid` and `id`? Are they both must be `pid`?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I assumed they were based on the result that the user provided. I think they are all supposed to be `pid`

Comment: @bluefeet I assume too, but OP is known exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify what RDBMS you are using but this will work in all versions:

```
select blog,
  id,
  max(case when attribute = 'pid' then value end) postid,
  max(case when attribute = 'date' then value end) date,
  max(case when attribute = 'title' then value end) title
from yourtable
group by blog, id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/58bb6/1)

If you are using a database with the `PIVOT` function, then your query will be like this:

```
select blog, id, pid as postid, date, title
from 
(
  select blog, id, attribute, value
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for attribute in (pid, date, title)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/58bb6/3)

The result for both will be:

```
| BLOG | ID | POSTID | DATE | TITLE |
-------------------------------------
|    p |  1 |   abc1 | abc2 |  abc3 |
|    p |  2 |   abc1 | abc2 |  abc3 |
|    p |  3 |   abc1 | abc2 |  abc3 |
```

Comment: @user1948914 Happy to help and welcome to StackOverflow, if this answer is helpful to you then be sure to accept it via the checkmark to the left of it.  It will help future visitors and you will get site reputation for it.